# Converting down from 10spd to 7spd

Tags: wheels

I'm building up a vintage mid 70s AlAn that cannot have it's rear drop outs cold set to a wider width.
I have a nice set of williams clincher wheels which are substantially lighter than anything oem (28/24)
By replacing the shimano freehub with a 7spd and the axel with a 7spd length is it possible shrink the rear hub width to 126mm from the 135?
(I realize I'll probably have to redish the rear wheel)

Comment: This question is now a year old - how did you get on with this project ?

Answer (score 2):

I kind of doubt it. The hub will still be 10-speed and I'm pretty sure that a 10-speed cassette is wider than a 7, so you won't get back all of the width (in fact I'm not sure you'll get any of it back). Even if you got some back, putting it into a 126 mm frame likely means that the wheel would be "over dished" (there would be a poor bracing angle on the right side spokes).

It seems like you'd do better to go looking for a NOS 7-speed hub so that you could build up a proper 126 mm wheel. If the flange sizes are the same you could probably reuse the existing spokes.

Comment: Maby I need to clarify. I want to take the existing hub (williams wheels)and remove the 10spd freehub and hollow axel and intall a 7spd freehub and 7spd hollow axel in its place. The flange to flange of the hub is the same width as my oem 7spd. The 7spd setup would be sis as the downtube shimano shifters have that capability and the rx100 derailleur is sis.  I am NOT looking to install a 10cog setup. I want to know whether I can convert these williams wheels to a 7spd setup. The williams are 1450 grm but rated for up to 220lbs rider weight.

Comment: The 7spd freehub on would go on the shimano hub now on the williams wheel.

Comment: Do you have the model of the Williams hub? I think the thing to do would be to look up the wheel building specs for it – specifically the center-to-flange dimensions and the width of the free hub body. If you can, I think it would be worth measuring the overall width of the hub (of the parts you'll be keeping). That number is going to be the minimum width you can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Freewheel bodies (the part that cassette is installed on) are generally non-interchangeable. It is not possible to take a freewheel body from an old 7-speed freehub and install it on a modern hub, especially one from a brand that has never made 7-speed hubs.

The exception to the rule are hubs/wheels that are made with both Shimano and Campagnolo compatible freewheel body, usually you can buy the other freehub body as a spare part.

Comment: I don't think the OP is talking about swapping bodies as part of this project. As I understand it his hope is to be able to replace the axle and redish the wheel and use a 7-speed cassette with a spacer. My concern is that the existing free hub body is 10-speed and wider than a 7-speed body which may mean that redishing the wheel to 126 mm may further compromise the strength of the right hand side of the wheel.

Comment: I understood the "By replacing the shimano freehub with a 7spd and the axel with a 7spd length" as replacing the freewheel body. But yes, replacing the axle and re-dishing the wheel isn't going to work.